# Can I search multiple indices using the InstantSearch Library?

Tags: algolia

My search objects in Algolia contain a field called SOURCE where I store which of our content silos I'm getting the content from.

I've used the InstantSearch library to create a nice search interface that uses the refinementList widget to let the user filter by the source system.  This works well enough.

Now I realize that I'd prefer to store each silo in a unique Algolia index, but I still want a single search UI.

I'm not seeing that the instantSearch library supports this.  Can it?  Can anyone point me to some sample code?

Comment: Can you share the current search implementation you have? And/or simplified examples of your dataset so that we better understand what you are trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

One way to let your users select the source would be to use a `sortBySelector` which lets you select different indices.

You can find more information about it in the [InstantSearch documentation](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#sortbyselector).